# Where does HDFS store it's files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

This might be very very basic. Where does a single node HDFS store the Files with respect to the actual File System ?

I am using the Cloudera VM to learn Hadoop.

For eg : A file called sample.txt at /home/cloudera can be copied to HDFS using

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/cloudera/sample.txt hdfs://localhost/user/cloudera/sample.txt
```

If I use Linux to search /user/cloudera directory in reality there is no such Directory.

Now suppose I change contents of /home/cloudera/sample.txt than these changes are not reflected in the File which is stored in HDFS.

I have two questions :

- Where does a single node HDFS store the Files with respect to the
  actual File System ?
- Why changes made to the original file are not
  reflected to the File on HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS data blocks are stored at
${dfs.data.dir} which by default points to ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data. In Linux system the value of hadoop.tmp.dir is /tmp. Check your 
hdfs-default.xml file if you want to override the defaults.

I'm not sure what you mean by the changes "not being reflected to the file in HDFS". These files are just data blocks which you can't just read and expect to have the same content as your file when accessed through hdfs://...

Comment: So it means we have two copies of the same File ?

Comment: You have to stop thinking in terms of files and start thinking in terms of blocks, pieces of files which are distributed across your data nodes. Whether you have two copies of the same block or not depends on the replication factor of your setup (default is 3).

Comment: Wow, sounds kool. So assume I have a cluster of two nodes and I copy my file on it. How can I know which new blocks were created because of this copy ?

Comment: you can run `hdfs fsck hdfs://localhost/user/cloudera/sample.txt -files -blocks -locations` command to get the list of blocks and locations for this particular file

Answer (score 1):

When you load data into HDFS from local filesystem (as shown in your example), HDFS splits it's content into data blocks which are stored in `dfs.datanode.data.dir` (option from [`hdfs-default.xml` config file](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)) of every machine running Data node daemon. Metadata (inluding name of every file, timestamps and so on) are managed by Name node daemon in separate database. File structure you can see in datanode data dir doesn't have anything to do with actual HDFS filesystem structure.

When you change the original file you have just uploaded into HDFS, this change has obviously no effect on data stored in HDFS volume. It's the same as if you copied file from usb flash drive into your home directory, then changed original file on usb wondering why the change didn't propagate in your homedir.